# Change Save entry to Publish possible?

Tags: templating, control-panel

I have a client that can't remember that save equals publish... is there a way to change the text from save to publish?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use JavaScript to find the button and change the text. Fortunately, the Craft CP contains jQuery, so it should be fairly easy.

This plugin should help speed up the process... Your JavaScript will get loaded on every page of the control panel.

> https://github.com/lindseydiloreto/craft-cpjs

Comment: Not sure which file, I would need to add js to do that... I know how to do it with js, jquery, etc. But which file would I need to modify in order to change that. I'm not sure which core files are used when creating/editing entries.

Comment: I edited my answer to make the plugin link a bit more obvious. You can put JS code directly into the plugin settings, or into a separate file. That JS will get loaded into every page of the CP, so it's really just a matter of targeting your DOM element correctly.

Comment: There's a feature request to change "Save" to "Publish" [here](http://feedback.buildwithcraft.com/forums/285221-feature-requests/suggestions/10315977-rename-save-button-to-publish-and-make-save-as-dra).

Comment: I've registered my dissent on that FR... @mmikkel, might be a good use-case for a plugin though!

Comment: Your dissent is well-founded. This isn't as straight-forward an issue as I first though :)